# PHP Login script - Should I attempt it?

Tags: php, authentication

I am getting started with PHP and I thought writing my own login/register script would give me  some decent exposure. However all of the posts I am seeing are quoting stuff like

"You're not a security expert, you shouldn't attempt this"

Should I attempt it? If I shouldn't what would you recommend?

Comment: I would attempt it.  Just don't use it in a production/commercial setting.  Use it strictly for the educational value.

Comment: anyone can build a login system. there's nothing particularly hard about it. it's when you try to make it apply to multiple systems and/or do funky advanced things that people run into trouble. e.g. being able to pedal around on a tricycle doesn't make you qualified to run the Tour de France

Comment: are you working on a framework like drupal or wordpress? if so, try to find a contribution for those guys.  otherwise, write your own, figure it out, it's not that difficult :)

Comment: I am thinking of doing it for the learning value first as I have only worked with HTML/CSS/Javascript (JQuery)

Answer (score 2):

There's no harm in trying something by yourself. As long as you're not in a position for which your login/register code risks stakeholders (financially?), you may learn a thing or two about security along the way.

Here's some documentation to get you started in the world of appsec (application security):

**XSS vulnerabilities**: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

**CSRF vulnerabilities**: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

**SQL Injections**: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: Thanks for the links, they will definatly help me going forward.

Comment: "As long as you're not in a position for which your login/register code risks stakeholders (financially?)" Right and all those pesky "normal" users don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

A login and registration system is probably the most fundamental thing you can do with session handling, so it's definitely a good idea. However, I would suggest only using logins with a username (no password) to start with. Passwords are a tricky business and there can be severe repercussions if you don't secure them. It's safer to experiment with a login system that only takes a username, then add a password once you've learned about encryption.

Comment: Great idea, thanks. I'll start with this to start learning.

Answer (score 0):

'Knowing is not enough, we must apply' - Bruce Lee

Good security practices can only be learnt by applyin them in real-world situations.

**Making secure Login and registration pages is as easy as**:

1. Getting a good DB table structure e.g table users columns username, name, password, email e.t.c
2. Getting user input
3. Sanitizing user input to prevent SQL injection if you are using the native mysql database driver. But better yet, teach yourself about prepared statements, MySQLi or abstraction layers like PDO that make portability a breeze.
4. [Hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) your passwords. Never store your passwords in plaintext But first salt the password before hashing it. Note, hash != encryption . Hash is practically irreversible (although theoritically reversible and some are quite collision-prone like Crc32. Hashes are e.g [MD5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php), [SHA256](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php), [SHA512](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php), [Bcrypt](http://phpmaster.com/why-you-should-use-bcrypt-to-hash-stored-passwords/) inorder of their strength.
5. Then make a query to store those values. Make sure that the username column is set to unique. You can't have two users having the same user name.

**During Login:**

-Check where the user/password combination is exact.

-For the password, pass it through the same salt-hashing algorithm you passed the original during registration.

-Set [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) variables to enable you to track the user and make sure that they are online.